# Order Fields priority

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, group-by

I am using this query:

```
select  o.orderno, 
        o.day, 
        a.name, 
        o.description, 
        a.adress, 
        o.quantity, 
        a.orderType, 
        o.status, 
        a.Line, 
        a.price,
        a.serial
  from  orders o
        inner join account a
            on o.orderid=a.orderid
  order by o.day
```

I am ordering by day. After sorting the results based on day, what is the next field that is considered on sorting,for the same day, what order is considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no further sorting. You'll get the results within each day in whatever order Oracle happened to retrieve them, which is not guaranteed in any way, and can be different for the same query being run multiple times. It depends on many things under the hood which you generally have no control over or even visibility of. You may see the results in an apparent order that suits you at the moment, but it could change for a future execution. Changing data will affect the execution plan, for example, which can affect the order to see the results.

If you need a specific order, or just want them returned in a consistent order every time you run the query, you must specify it in the `order by` clause.

This is something Tom Kyte often stresses; for example [in this often-quoted article](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/order-in-court.html).

Answer (score 0):

It tries to order by the unique/primary key. In this case, orderno if it is your primary key.

However, your query is laden with errors. 
e.g. The table aliases are used in the SELECT clause but are not specified in the FROM

Comment: It is NOT guaranteed. It depends on: 
 1. previously executed queries that contain an ORDER BY clause
 2. what Oracle finds in the cache
Best if you specified which is the next column you need the result sorted on.